# Time tracking data (Toggl and .csv) to Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, time-management

I want to turn my data from [Toggl](https://www.toggl.com/) (which is my time tracker) to Google Calendar.

I have a .csv export from Toogl, and it [looks like this](http://cl.ly/image/2l2T0p132v3m) but with 100 rows or more. I've been tracking my time with Toggl for over a year.

I have looked at iBiz, Billings, Harvest, Toggl, Paymo, Clicktime, tickspot, Freshbooks. They're not good enough.

Why do I need my Toggl data in google calendar? Because that way, I can analyse my time spent the way I want. This is what I need to get:

1. Weekly view of the calendar – a visual representation of my work.
2. Some key figures.

Example of key figures:

- A time block's median/average time
- how long my days are on average
- how many time blocks a day I have
- total work time per week
- total work time per projekt per week (not the GTD-definition; I have three current big projects).

The neat thing about google calendar is that I can satisfy the need for visual view, and export my calendar using gcal2excel.com from where I am able to do some excel formulas and find out the numbers of my key figures.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar but simpler problem with [timetracker](http://www.theproductivitygame.com/TimeTracker/), a gagdet added to your Google Calendar which is exactly what I needed, it sums hours grouped by tags present in your events. I hope it helps to someone else, has been hard to find.

I'd love to hear the solution you came with btw